# How to enable keyboard interaction with desktop when icons are hidden?

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, desktop

Windows 10 prevents me from keyboard interacting with the desktop when my icons are visually hidden by Windows (right click on desktop>display>hide the icons). For instance, left click on the desktop then typing "PI" then typing Enter should open my Pictures folder shortcut.

In this situation, how to enable the keyboard interaction with my desktop files without re-enabling the icon display or by keeping my desktop visually as clear as possible?

I thought of re-enabling the icon display then gathering the files into a pile of icons but I didn't find a way to do this.

```
Original question before edit:

How to make a pile of icons on Windows 10 desktop?

I have too many icons on my desktop so I want to gather all of them in the same point, somewhere in the corner, to free up space.

I tried to hide the icons straight with the classic Windows feature  but this disallows the keyboard interactions with them.
```

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, it's possible that you got a bit carried away if you have **so** many desktop icons that they are unmanageable.  The desktop is supposed to provide quick access to a number of crucial shortcuts, not necessarily *all* of them.  It sounds like your ideal solution would be to create a sub-folder called "Shortcuts" under your Windows profile (within Documents or Downloads, perhaps), move all of those icons there, and then create a shortcut on your desktop to that folder.  That would essentially accomplish what you want.

Comment: @Run5k Thanks for you reply. All my desktop icons are specifically made to provide quick access to my key files and folders. I really can't delete any of them.
I do have a subfolder with all my shortcuts. I quickly open this subfolder with a keyboard shortcut when I have plenty of opened windows hiding visually my desktop. But for some reasons, the fastest way to access my key files is still my desktop (one click on the desktop+keyboard shortcut+enter = open the file). I know it's kind of a brat's request but the desktop thing is really a game changer for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can move some of them to a folder on your desktop. Right click on your desktop and select 'New ... Folder'. You can then name the folder what you like. Then you can simply 'drag and drop' the other icons into this folder.
Double click on the folder to open it and access your other apps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try [this.](https://www.makeuseof.com/answers/can-change-windows-desktop-behave-little-like-android-ios/)

Also theres [Nimiplaces](https://www.ampercent.com/nimiplaces-organize-desktop-folders-and-shortcuts-into-separate-stacks/5790/)
and [Fences](https://www.stardock.com/products/fences/)

The 1st one, it's kind of like Android or iOS way of managing lots of apps in your screen but you put them in a 'folder' but instead of opening a new window it only shows you the shortcuts that are stacked inside that 'folder'

hope it helps. cheers!